# Flutter - Firebase auth onAuthStateChanged does not show dashboard

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new to Flutter and I am having some issues implementing Firebase authentication.

So, I have a MaterialApp widget and I have registered some routes. I have a wrapper StreamBuilder that listens to Firebase onAuthStateChanged event and every time I have a new user value, MaterialApp is receiving that new value.

My problem is that I can not figure the best way to navigate user either to login screen (if no current user) or to dashboard (if current user is valid). Can you please help me with that? Every solution I found on the web does not implement routes and instead they all return a widget. Is there a way to make this with routes?

My main class code below :

```
void main() async {
  // Catch all exceptions and print them to log.
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    logger.e("", details.exception, details.stack);
  };

  // Initialize main engines.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  // Start main app.
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en', 'US'),
          Locale('el', 'GR')
        ],
        path: 'assets/translations',
        fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
        useFallbackTranslations: true,
        child: App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // Future to initialize firebase.
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "*****************",
        authDomain: "*****************",
        projectId: "*****************",
        storageBucket: "*****************",
        messagingSenderId: "*****************",
        appId: "*****************",
        measurementId: "*****************")
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          logger.e("Error while retrieving firebase credentials.", snapshot.error);
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream: Authentication.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // Extract user from snapshot.
              final User? user = snapshot.data;

              return StreamProvider<TreatUser?>(
                create: (_) => TreatUser.streamUser(context, user?.uid),
                initialData: null,
                child: MaterialApp(
                  title: "[Dashboard]",
                  theme: Themes.mainTheme(context),
                  darkTheme: Themes.mainThemeDark(context),
                  themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
                  localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
                  supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
                  locale: context.locale,
                  routes: {
                    AppRoutes.login: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                    AppRoutes.passReset: (context) => ResetPassScreen(),
                    AppRoutes.dashboard: (context) => DashboardScreen(),
                    AppRoutes.user_profile: (context) => UserProfile(),
                    AppRoutes.items: (context) => ItemsScreen(),
                  },
                  initialRoute: user != null ? AppRoutes.dashboard : AppRoutes.login,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }

        logger.d("Firebase not connected yet. Waiting.");

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are multiple Scaffolds under the Material App (before the auth process). So the authStateChanges gets replaced by another and doesn't respond.

The solution to this is using FirebaseAuth.currentUser in the initialRoute or home Parameter.

After Login, manually push the Dashboard and Remove all previous screens.

Similarly, you can do it for Logging out.